# Writing my own test-runner for boost test

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I try to understand how to write and use my own test-runner with boost (version 1.42).

With using my own test-runner as described [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/usage-variants/extern-test-runner.html) I want to accomplish the following tasks

- Use my own main()
- Take my own decision when and under what circumstances I run all test cases

So far reading the documentation I understood, that I can accomplish this behaviour by providing my own test-runner.

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK

#include <boost/test/prg_exec_monitor.hpp>

#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int i, int j)
{
    return i + j;
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(universeInOrder)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(add(2, 2) == 4);
}


int boost::prg_exec_monitor_main(int (*)(int, char**), int, char**){
      printf("Test me!");
    }
```

I get the output

> Test me!

So far - so good. But:

- What's the difference between prg_exec_monitor_main and a test-runner?
- How do I get a list of all registered test cases?
- How can I start these tests?